# GitLab CE (omnibus) - Apache Letsencrypt

Tags: apache, lets-encrypt, gitlab-omnibus

i am running GitLab under apache as per documentation and instructions.
Now i would like to secure it with letsencrypt, but have no idea hot to let certbot/letsencrypt access /.well-known which is needed to have it issue an certificate by that method.

I know i can do it with DNS, but that is cumbersome as it can't really be automated.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a couple of additional configuration lines to your Apache. Mainly you'll need to exclude requests with .well-known being intercepted and processed by gitlab-workhorse:

https://serverfault.com/questions/850175/apache-2-4-gitlab-letsencrypt-not-working